# Viewing/Collecting Service Fabric ETW Events OnPrem

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, etw

We are trying to view Service ETW Events in an OnPrem cluster.  The long term plan will be to install an ElasticSearch cluster to send the events to.  I don't have time to build that out this week, instead I need to understand why my App is blowing up.

We have installed Microsoft Message Analyzer on one of the node servers and I can connect with a live session to view the Cluster ETW Events Service Fabric System Provider.

I would like to be able to view the Application ETW Events.  I've followed the instructions in the article here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostic-collect-logs-without-an-agent

This article seems to focus on 3 files, eventFlowConfig.json, Program.cs and ServiceEventSource.cs.

EventFlowConfig.Json has:

```
    "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "EventSource",
      "sources": [
        { "providerName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services" },
        { "providerName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors" },
        { "providerName": "TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI"  }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "filters": [
    {
      "type": "drop",
      "include": "Level == Verbose"
    }
   ],
   "outputs": [
    {
      "type": "StdOutput"
    }
```

In program.cs I have:

```
  using (var diagnosticsPipeline = ServiceFabricDiagnosticPipelineFactory.CreatePipeline("CacheApp-CacheAPI-DiagnosticsPipeline"))
                {

                    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("EndpointType",
                    context => new Endpoint(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(Endpoint).Name);
                    // Prevents this host process from terminating so services keeps running. 
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
```

ServiceEventSource.cs has:

```
 [EventSource(Name = "TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI")]
```

I package and deploy fine, but using MSMA I don't know how to attach to the Application Provider?  I think I would be adding a "Custom Provider" but it asks for a GUID.  Is there someway to find this Guid?  I'm assuming I want to add the customer provider for my specific ServiceFabric Application of type:

"TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI"

Thanks in advance,
Greg

Comment: I've installed PerfView on the server.  I can point to the process to create a dump file of the process.  This doesn't really do much for me.

@yoApe using the advanced options was useful.  The Provider Browser is accessible from there, I can not see my TMHP provider in the list, nor is Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services or Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors.

I'm wondering if I've missed something in the ServiceFabric App?  The Provider Type doesn't seem to be registered at all.  The next step is looking at Karol's tool to see if I can get it to work.  My thought is SF should be doing this?

Comment: FYI I'm still working on this.  I've attempted the PerfView approach with little success.  I'm working on it and will update the group in a bit

Comment: Ok so I was able to solve this specific problem by using the command line launch of PerfView listed below.  I'm not necessarily seeing all of the events I would expect but we are working on figuring that out.  I am standing up a ElasticStack and heading in that direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use PerFView instead, Vance has an article on how to view EventSource based events in PerfView https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/07/09/introduction-tutorial-logging-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/ The '*' in front of the EventSource name is important.

Here's some instructions for how to view actor events, your custom EventSource should be the same pattern.

The Actor and ReliableServices are EventSource based so to view them in PerfView you have to follow the instructions on Vance’s blog. Don't forget the '*'!!!

1. Start PerfView with a command line like this: perfview /onlyproviders=*Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors
2. You can collect using Collect | Collect | Start Collection. Make sure that the Advanced Options | Additional Providers field contains =*Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors
3. When you finish collecting they are viewable under Events

[image]

Comment: Thanks Todd, what do you think of Karol's comment above?  I think the current question is whether service fabric registers the provider type or if that's a manual step that needs to be done?  I've installed perfView now and I'm trying to see if it also has issues finding the Provider like MSMA does.  Thanks,

Comment: Yeah, based on what I'm seeing PerfView want to open a file, but I don't think ServiceFabric will actually create any files.  It will only use the output types of ElasticSearch and StdOutput ect.  Maybe I'm just being ignorant but there is not a way to use the article above and run the ServiceFabric app executable in that manner from what I understand?

Answer (score 1):

The Guid of a .NET EventSource based Event Provider is actually based on the name of the provider, it is generated using a hash algorithm. This blog post has a short description of it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dcook/2015/09/08/etw-provider-names-and-guids/. You can use the supplied ETWGuid.exe to generate the Guid for your provider:

```
C:\code> .\EtwGuid.exe TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI

TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER(
    g_hMyProvider,
    "TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI",
    // {9deef099-8d1a-568a-1618-08ffbb7146b3}
    (0x9deef099,0x8d1a,0x568a,0x16,0x18,0x08,0xff,0xbb,0x71,0x46,0xb3));
```

So the Guid for `TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI` would be `9deef099-8d1a-568a-1618-08ffbb7146b3`. This only works for .NET EventSources btw, other Event Providers may have other ways of setting the guid for a provider.

You can then look for that provider in your Microsoft Message Analyzer, [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) or any other tool for ETW viewing.

As for the Microsoft supplied Event Providers you have three built-in you should look at for Service Fabric:

- `Microsoft-ServiceFabric` - `CBD93BC2-71E5-4566-B3A7-595D8EECA6E8` - These ere the 'low-level' Service Fabric activities
- `Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors` - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-diagnostics)
- `Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-diagnostics

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  When I try to add the custom provider with that GUID and TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI I get the the provider is not installed.  Are there some steps I need to do to install the provider type?  I was thinking when service fabric either uploaded the package to the image store or when it created an instance of that application that it would create the provider type.  Im reading up on this guy now but I was hoping SF would handle this: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc432688.aspx]

Comment: Actually that's the wrong article above, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714799.aspx

Comment: Are you running on your local development cluster when your are testing this or on a real cluster? If you are running the dev cluster I believe it uninstalls the provider when you stop (and remove) the application (unless you have changed the default behavior).

Comment: You should be able to run PerfView on the node (or your local machine) and then add the provider guid in the Advanced Options > Additional Providers box and then start collection. If you then run the service you should see the events collected from your provider now in the log.

Comment: By default `EventSource` is using dynamic manifest generation; that does not work with tools that expect basic ETW providers registered with the system. But you can use [EventRegister tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister/) to generate and register a manifest for your EventSource.

Comment: @KarolZ, PerfView displays events logged from EventSource in SF applications, does SF automatically register Event Providers when hosting the services?

Comment: @KarolZ What else do I need to do to use the EventSource tool?  I've installed it with the service fabric project open, packed and deployed to the cluster.  Should that cover it?  I googled and had a hard time finding doco.  Thanks

Comment: @yoape PerfView has intimate understanding of EventSources and does not require ETW provider registration. Some other MS tools, like Azure Diagnostics extension, do to. If you look at the docs for Azure Diagnostics configuration schema https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-schema-1dot3-to-1dot5 you will notice it differentiates between "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration" and "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration". 

SF does not automatically register EventSources as ETW providers

Comment: @gperrego To monitor your application ideally you would use a tool, like Azure Diagnostics extension or PerfView that understands about EventSources. Assuming this is not available, you need to register your EventSource as a regular, manifest-based ETW provider, using the EventRegister tool. In the context of a Service Fabric application that could be done as part of the application startup task. SF will _not_ do this automatically for you.

Comment: @KarolZ Launching PerfView with the command line listed above that Todd shared (perfview /onlyproviders=*TMHP-CacheApp-CacheAPI) looks for events with the same GUID that yoape created above.  Considering you wrote the article I'm referring to in the Azure Documentation above can you take one more look at my set up and let me know if I've missed something?

Comment: @KarolZ I am getting some events via my set up above, looks like I'm only getting the startup and register events.  We are trying to figure out why but wanted to give you a heads up.  Thanks

Comment: @gperrego If you _can_ capture ServiceTypeRegistered event, but not other events from the same EventSource, my first suspicion would be that the other events are simply not raised. You said in the original post that the app is "blowing up", maybe the service code never has a chance to call event methods and thus raise events you are expecting?

Comment: @KarolZ we got past the "blowing up" part by removing some claims based security so the app is up and running.  I'm thinking that there is something like that happening also.  I'm still digging into this and will update you in a bit.  Thanks again.